# programmatic image retrieval from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to be able to programmatically retrieve images from a Google Sheet. I have been able to successfully insert images in cells using the code:

```
=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?
export=view&id=13dx6Hl6tQj4gzlafj_7jo3k0X4fwQ7jtzg",2)
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish.  What attempts have you made at coding this so far?

Comment: Hi..just trying to efficiently retrieve the images which have already been stored in Google Sheets. The retrieved images are to be used in a GAS program written with HtmlService for a type of slideshow. I already tried thoroughly searching the web documentation for a function to do this but have not found any so I have not made any attempts. Would like to find a retrieval function if anyone knows of any.

Answer (score 0):

How about following sample script? Unfortunately, there are no methods for retrieving directly images on spreadsheet using GAS. So I use the method which retrieves URL from `=image(URL)` and retrieves the image from the URL. In this case, `=image(URL)` has to be in the cell. Please confirm this.

#### Sample script :

```
var cell = "A1"; // Cell address with the function of "=image()"
var filename = "samplename"; // Output filename

var image = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getFormula();
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(image.match(/\"(.+)\"/)[1]).getBlob();
DriveApp.createFile(blob.setName(filename));
```

**Flow :**

1. Retrieve `=image(URL)` using `getFormula()`.
2. Retrieve URL from `=image(URL)`.
3. Retrieve file blob using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` from the URL.
4. Output the file blob as a file.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Really appreciate the clever script above, Thank You.. but not an Answer as I am looking for a way to retrieve the images directly from Google Sheets, not from the source URL which I already know how to do. I want to read images from Google Sheets directly for the best performance as the images already reside there in some form. The images are stored in Google sheets for organization purposes which a spreadsheet does well.

Comment: @user1387318 Unfortunately, there are no methods for retrieving directly images on spreadsheet using GAS. I wrote this in my answer. But I'm sorry I couldn't be helpful for you.